# Pythonic shortcut (syntax sugar) for nested self.__parent__.__parent__

Tags: python, pyramid

I have this case in Python (with Pyramid framwork), where I'm trying to check for condition.
Here is the code:

```
if some_condition:
    value = self.__parent__.__parent__.__parent__.method()
else:
    value = self.__parent__.__parent__.method()
```

The question is, is there more pythonic way (syntax sugar shortcut) for representing `__parent__.__parent__...` dynamically?

I know that there is Python syntax like this:

```
value1, value2, value3 = (None,) * 3
```

Is there something similar and dynamic for my case?
I searched in Google, in Python documentation, in Reddit source code, in Open Stack source code, and I spend 2 days in searching, so decided to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such syntax in python.

However you may indeed implement custom method for obtaining a list of parent resources:

```
def find_ancestors(resource):
    ancestors = [resource]
    while hasattr(ancestors[-1], '__parent__'):
        ancestors.append(ancestors[-1].__parent__)
    return ancestors
```

Or a method to iterate them:

```
def iter_ancestors(resource):
    yield resource
    while hasattr(resource, '__parent__'):
        resource = resource.__parent__
        yield resource
```

Also, I'm not sure if such way is the appropriate one. I think you should take a look at [find_interface(..)](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/traversal.html#pyramid.traversal.find_interface) method and somehow manage to define appropriate interfaces for your resources to locate them. Doing such way your code will look like:

```
value = find_interface(self, ResourceA if some_condition else ResourceB).method()
```

**UPDATE:** The code provided by @Dunes in his answer is another good approach to get ancestors by their index.

Comment: I know for find_interface, but needed to know if there is some syntax shortcut that I miss. Anyway I guess that there is no such flexible dynamic one.

Comment: @intel As I said, I don't know such syntax either.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the parent chain you could always write a helper method to get a node at a given depth. Though this might be less legible.

eg.

```
def get_parent(item, depth):
    original_depth = depth
    try:
       while depth:
           item = item.__parent__
           depth -= 1
       return item
    except AttributeError:
        raise AttributeError("No parent node found at depth {}".format(
            original_depth-depth))
```

Usage:

```
get_parent(self, 3).method()
```